# Solr is not able to index my table

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

My solr mainpage is not showing any error. But its not taking the information from the desired table .

DATA-CONFIG.XML

```
<dataConfig> 
 <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/market_place" user="root" password="student" batchSize="1" />  
 <document name="persons">   
  <entity name="courses" query="SELECT * FROM courses">    
   <field column="id" name="id"/>    
   <field column="name" name="name"/>    
   <field column="duration" name="duration"/>    
   <field column="fee" name="fee"/>    
  <!-- <field column="UNIVERSITY" name="university"/>   -->
  </entity>  
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

changes i made in solrconfig.xml

```
 <lib dir="../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="../../dist/" regex="mysql-connector-java-\d.*\.jar" />



 <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">  
 <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
 </lst> 
  </requestHandler>
```

Changes in schema.xml

```
 <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
     <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
     <field name="duration" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
     <field name="fee" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: Please give us more details about steps you're doing. If you called the /dataimport service, you should have some message in the log. If you don't, check the log level and set that to DEBUG for the DataImportHandler package, then retry.

Comment: If you have trouble getting Solr to log something, refer to [the reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Configuring+Logging) or [the wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging).